# why append menu_order in wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

query is simple but post not get properly and ordering

```
 $args = array(
                        'post_type'=> 'post',
                        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'order'    => 'DESC',
                        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3
                    );

*SQL QUERY*

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count' ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Is there a `pre_get_posts` that is affecting your query somewhere?

Comment: Can you please show the WP_Query?